# routing traffic to remote webserver within VPN, via reverse proxy

Tags: vpn, webserver, reverse-proxy

What I'm trying to achieve, is posted in below picture: the different PI's each host a webserver, and are connected with a dongle to the 4G network (in remote areas). Since they have shared IP's on those dongles, I want to bring them into my VPN so they can be accessed either publicly or through my home network.

Idea for public access, is through different ports, e.g. mydns.com:81 for webserver 1 and mydns.com:82 for webserver 2.

So, the Pi's are connected with 4G and are an OpenVPN client (10.0.8.10) connected to the OpenVPNServer on my NAS(192.168.15.4).  This NAS is behind my router and switch.

I'm trying to use Reverse Proxy on my NAS to redirect the (public) http traffic to the Webservers on the PI.

My router is forwarding traffic from port 81 to the NAS.
My NAS has the reverse proxy set up, where traffic from domain name MyDNS on port 81 has as destination 10.0.8.10 (IP of the PI running the webserver).

Yet, it is not working, and think I'm missing something: I can not access mydns:81 from a public IP address.

What I can do:

- I can go to the website 10.0.8.10:80 when I'm on the VPN with my laptop
- I can ping from the NAS (19.168.15.4) to the OpenVPN Client (10.0.8.10)
- the NAS is listening to port 85
- from this remote PI, I can ping to my entire LAN (thus ip 192.168.15.x)

**What should I do or add to make this work?**

Should I add a route from the Pi (webserver) to the NAS? (I don' t think so...)

Should I add a hostname in my webserver config file?

Setup:

- Raspberry PI's 5, running bookworm, OpenVPN Client working
- webserver on the PI's via Caddy
- NAS = QNAP NAS, running OpenVPN server
- L3 Switch managing different VLAN's

[setup VPN home network and public network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7vZZ.png)

Comment: From your description, I think you can just forward public port 81/82 directly to each pi from the router (most let you set a different inside port), unless the proxy has some other purpose? This part about your proxy config is not correct: "where traffic from domain name MyDNS" - should this be "traffic *for*", like it's filtering on hostname?

Comment: ok, but this would assume my router knows about VPN network; which he does not, since it is my QNAP (behind my router) who is acting as VPN server.
On the QNAP, I need to route the traffic (as reverse proxy) to the VPN IP of the PI.  It is traffic "from", and not traffic "for".

Comment: that makes sense if you are not bridging your VPN network to LAN - otherwise you just need a route on the router. Have you checked the proxying works, like can your LAN client access the site via `192.168.15.4:85`?